# PHP How to get value from function that checks between multiple date ranges in array

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables

I have a function that checks if today's date falls in between multiple date intervals in an array. The only thing I need is for this function to return the $location value in the checkRange function.

```
function promoDates(){
    $current = strtotime("now");

    // Array gives a place, start date, and end date
    $intervals = array(
        //The $current start time falls between the dates in washington array
        array('washington', strtotime("2015-01-08 00:00"), strtotime("2015-01-30 00:00")),
        array('california', strtotime("2015-06-02 00:00"), strtotime("2015-06-17 00:00")),
        array('texas', strtotime("2015-02-12 00:00"), strtotime("2015-02-27 00:00")),
        array('ney-york', strtotime("2015-05-12 00:00"), strtotime("2015-05-26 00:00")),
        array('tennessee', strtotime("2015-10-29 00:00"), strtotime("2015-11-12 00:00")),
        array('utah', strtotime("2015-09-15 00:00"), strtotime("2015-09-30 00:00")),
        array('florida', strtotime("2015-11-12 00:01"), strtotime("2015-11-27 00:00"))
    );

    function checkRange($location, $startDate, $endDate, $currentDate){
        if ($currentDate >= $startDate && $currentDate <= $endDate){
            // Successfully echos 'washington' to page
            echo $location."<br>";
            return $location;
        }
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++){
        checkRange($intervals[$i][0], $intervals[$i][1], $intervals[$i][2], $current);
    }
    //This does not echo the location from the checkRange function
    echo checkRange();
}
```

I just need help getting the promoDates function to return what the checkRange function is echoing. Is there a way I can set a variable inside the checkRange function and return it in the promoDates function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you arent passing in any arguments to the `checkRange()` function... I would also change the signature of the checkRange function to take an array for interval:

```
function promoDates() {

    $current = strtotime("now");

    // Array gives a place, start date, and end date
    $intervals = array(
        //The $current start time falls between the dates in washington array
        array('washington', strtotime("2015-01-08 00:00"), strtotime("2015-01-30 00:00")),
        array('california', strtotime("2015-06-02 00:00"), strtotime("2015-06-17 00:00")),
        array('texas', strtotime("2015-02-12 00:00"), strtotime("2015-02-27 00:00")),
        array('ney-york', strtotime("2015-05-12 00:00"), strtotime("2015-05-26 00:00")),
        array('tennessee', strtotime("2015-10-29 00:00"), strtotime("2015-11-12 00:00")),
        array('utah', strtotime("2015-09-15 00:00"), strtotime("2015-09-30 00:00")),
        array('florida', strtotime("2015-11-12 00:01"), strtotime("2015-11-27 00:00"))
    );

    // we will use this like a filter
    function checkRange($currentDate, $promo) {
        list($location, $startDate, $endDate) = $promo;
       // return true or false
      return (($currentDate >= $startDate) && ($currentDate <= $endDate));
    }

    // loop over the intervals until we find a match then return it:
    foreach($intervals as $promoData) {
       if (checkRange($current, $promoData) === true) {
          return $promoData[0];
       }
    }

    // return null if we do not find any
    return null;     
}
```

And usage would look like:

```
echo promoDates();
```

Comment: The arguments were being passed in the for loop. I actually fixed it by returning the function inside the loop but I like your solution as well.

Comment: Actually my fix didn't completely work, but yours did. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

edit: I actually just fixed it by following @prodigitalson advice and checking if each loop iteration is true or false, then returning the value where it is true.

```
function checkRange($startDate, $endDate, $currentDate, $loc){
    if ($currentDate >= $startDate && $currentDate <= $endDate){
        return true;
    } else{
        return null;
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++){
    if(checkRange($intervals[$i][1], $intervals[$i][2], $current, $intervals[$i][0]) == true){
        return $intervals[$i][0];
    }
}
```

and removing the echo checkRange(); at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry, I just removed my answer, it was complete garbage, I should have read your question more carefully. But your solution has a flaw too: It will only ever check the first location and return the value from checkRange (either the name of the first location or NULL).

Comment: I just fixed it ^^ Thank you for bringing that up!